# Does "eth_getCode" return the init bytecode or the deployed bytecode?

Tags: json-rpc, bytecode

The Ethereum JSON-PRC spec contains an [eth_getCode](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_getCode) method, but it is not specified what is being retrieved:

1. Init bytecode (including constructor)
2. Deployed bytecode (without constructor)

Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `eth_getCode` returns the bytecode associated with the address in the Ethereum world state, that will be the deployed bytecode (or runtime bytecode).

The init bytecode could be obtained from the deployment transaction's data field, unless it was created by a contract in which case you have to trace the transaction to obtain the details.

Comment: how output will be different for "pending" and "latest" block param?

Comment: @Proton The output will change if at some point in between the contract destroy itself. After a contract is destroyed the runtime bytecode should be empty.