# Difference between `bytecode` and `deployedBytecode` (especially for contracts with constructor args)

Tags: solidity, hardhat, bytecode, deployed-bytecode

Suppose I have a contract like

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract MyContract {
    constructor(string arg1, uint arg2) {
        ...
    }    
    ...
}
```

When I compile the solidity contract (actually I'm using hardhat), we get an artifact file like `artifacts/contracts/MyContract.sol/MyContract.json`, which includes `bytecode` and `deployedBytecode` fields. What are the differences?

I've googled and found some [docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/artifacts#compilation-artifacts) but its not yet clear, especially because `bytecode` and `deployedBytecode` are generated without constructor parameters.

- the concatenation of `bytecode` and consctuctor parameters are send in the deployed transaction?
- the byte code of the deployed stored on Ethereum is `deployedBytecode` and constructor parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to hardhat document : `deployedBytecode: A "0x"-prefixed hex string of the unlinked runtime/deployed bytecode. If the contract is not deployable, this has the string "0x"`. It means deployed bytecode is runtime bytecode.

1. What is the difference : the initialize code and its parameters: and boostrap the contract `runtime bytecode` and its initial environment (e.g. state storages, including running the constructor logic).
2. Yes encoded params are appended to the end of bytecode. Read more: https://docs.blockscout.com/for-users/abi-encoded-constructor-arguments
3. `deployedBytecode` or `runtime bytecode` is what you see on etherscan or when you query `eth_getCode` using ethereum node's RPC: [Does "eth_getCode" return the init bytecode or the deployed bytecode?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108152/does-eth-getcode-return-the-init-bytecode-or-the-deployed-bytecode)

Hope the above helps, you can read more about that here
[Difference between bytecode and runtime bytecode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32234/difference-between-bytecode-and-runtime-bytecode)

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answers and links, now I understand better.

- Input data of deploy transaction = `bytecode` + constructor params
- runtime bytecode = `deployedBytecode` = return of `getCode`

(where `bytecode` and `deployedBytecode` are found in the artifact JSON file)